# Relative positions of substrings

Tags: string, vbscript

I have to write a VBScript for a text in a paragraph to be searched for and find out the positions of the text from the last location.

Suppose, if the sentence is:

```
This is my first paragraph and my first try
```

and I am going to have to find out the position of `"my"`, then the first position will be 9 and the second will be 32. But instead of printing 32, I have to print the next position from 9. When I execute this code, I get the result 9 and 32.

```
Dim X,i

For i=1 to 10
  X=Instr(i, "This is my first paragraph and my first try", "my", 1)

  i=X+1

  msgbox i
Next
```

What the problem is here is the `For` interval loop! I have to adjust the `For` loop per the text to be searched for. Can it be done using a constant interval? This will print values 9 and 32, but I need to print the latter value as 23.

Comment: Why not just add an if condition with the constant interval? or you are try to finding a performance answer?.

Comment: This is just an example. If I have to find all positions of the text, the for loop needs to be adjusted accordingly.

Comment: A `For` loop is not the right tool for finding an unknown number of occurrences of a substring. Consider using a different loop type. The distance between two occurences can be calculated as the difference between the current and the previous position.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers What different loop type do you suggest and why?

Comment: @Jhoopins A `Do` or `While` loop, obviously, to avoid needless iterations.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: What programming logic should be used to find out the difference between the current and the previous position?

Comment: @DrasticdreamerDrasticity You [gotta be kidding me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers *obviously*... Your comment was vague (albeit correct), I was just trying to draw out something that points the user in some direction other than "not that way".

Comment: @Jhoopins This appears to be a homework question, so I'm deliberately being vague.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a couple of options.

1. Use a `Do While` loop:

   ```
   Const SOME_TEXT = "This is my first paragraph and my first try"

   Dim intPos, intLast
   intPos = InStr(1, SOME_TEXT, "my")

   Do While intPos > 0
       WScript.Echo intPos - intLast
       intLast = intPos
       intPos = InStr(intPos + 1, SOME_TEXT, "my")
   Loop
   ```
2. Use a regex and take advantage of the `FirstIndex` property of the `Match` object:

   ```
   Dim re
   Set re = New RegExp
   re.Pattern = "\bmy\b"
   re.Global = True

   Dim m, i
   Set m = re.Execute("This is my first paragraph and my first try")

   For i = 0 To m.Count - 1
       If i = 0 Then MsgBox m(i).FirstIndex + 1 Else MsgBox m(i).FirstIndex - m(i-1).FirstIndex
   Next
   ```

Comment: @Bond: Thanks for the options. The first one is quite simple and it works for me. Thank you once again.